# Опечатка в варианте жалобы на ответ

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, нет-в-transifex

В вариантах жалобы на ответ есть такой пункт:

> **вопрос** необходимо удалить из-за проблем с качеством
>
> Ответ имеет
> серьезные проблемы с форматированием или контентом. Ответ вряд ли
> удастся исправить с помощью правок, поэтому его необходимо удалить.

Видимо копировали из вариантов для вопроса и забыли исправить.
Здесь стоит сделать следующую замену:
"вопрос" => "ответ".

**Дефект воспроизводится на ответах с нулевым рейтингом.**

Comment: Проверьте, воспроизводится сейчас этот дефект?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, Теперь я этого варианта вообще не вижу.

Comment: Появился вариант, но ничего не изменилось.

Comment: Недавноее обсуждение в чате. http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/25500802#25500802

Comment: Поменял пару строк, не ранее 19 ноября нужно проверить.

Answer (score 4):

Конечно надо исправить. Ещё небольшое улучшение:

> ответ необходимо удалить из-за проблем с качеством
>
> Ответ имеет серьезные проблемы с форматированием или **содержимым**. Ответ вряд ли удастся **улучшить**  с помощью правок, поэтому его **стоит**  удалить.

Убрал повторение "править" - "правок".